# Chrome developer tool trace function sequences

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am a newbie to Chrome developer tool and I found it is very powerful. Currently, I am looking for a way to trace the flow of functions when I open a webpage and also, I am wondering is there s how can I find which function does an element trigger when it is clicked. Here are some examples:

1) Tracing function sequences:
For example, there are 20 functions in my script. Some of the functions will call the other functions. I would like to trace the function calls. Like which function is called first and then what functions are called following by this function. Since these 20 functions are pretty huge, it is quite hard to follow the sequence by just looking at the script.

2) Which function does an element trigger in javascript: 
For example, I have one button on the webpage, there is one or are more functions associated with this element. By using the Event Listener of Chrome developer tool, I can only see some DOM elements under "Click" rather what function it is associated with.

Is there a way to find associated functions?

I appreciate you help!

Comment: 1. you can get with a profile. 2. you can get with a stack trace or breakpoint.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What is a profile? Get with a stack trace, do you mean I can add 20 breakpoint for each function and then run the page see how it goes ? Thanks!

Comment: use the "Profiles" tab of devtools to get a list of functions called during the profile.

Comment: I will play around with Profiles, never used it before. But how to use stack trace to get which function an element trigger?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. In **Sources** panel, there is a **Call Stack** tab, in which you could see the function call stack when code execution was halted at break points.

   [image]
2. In **Elements** panel, there is an **Event Listeners** tab, in which you could see all event handlers bond to the element, as well as where it is in source code.

   [image]

I suggest you to read some tutorials, for example [**this**](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools) and [**this**](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/chrome-developer-tools), and there are more. So that you could know more about it and boost your development.

Comment: Thank you very much Leo and this is very helpful. It will largely decrease my debugging time :)

Comment: Hi Leo, I have another question regarding to your 2). In my code, I am actually using Jquery, so in the Event Listeners tab, rather than seeing the actually function it calls in my js file, it always show jquery.js:2. Have you ever met this situation before ?

Comment: @GuifanLi I guess you were using a dist version of jquery, which is mangled and compressed. Load a sourcemap may fix the debugging issue.